# ATTR{index} always 0, how to write persistent udev rule?

Tags: usb, udev

I have 2 identical USB devices. Only one persistent symlink is created:

```
/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-fushicai_usbtv007_300000000002-video-index0
```

I think it's because /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules uses `ATTR{index}` to distinguish them, but it's always zero:

```
for d in /dev/video*; do echo $d; udevadm info -a $d | grep 'ATTRS.manufacturer\|ATTR.index\|ATTR.name'; echo ; done
/dev/video0
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="Loopback video device 0"

/dev/video1
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="Loopback video device 1"

/dev/video2
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="Loopback video device 2"

/dev/video3
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="Loopback video device 3"

/dev/video4
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="usbtv"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="fushicai"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.2.5-1-ARCH ehci_hcd"

/dev/video5
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="usbtv"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="fushicai"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.2.5-1-ARCH ehci_hcd"

/dev/video6
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="stk1160"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Syntek Semiconductor"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.2.5-1-ARCH xhci-hcd"
```

Who assigns this attribute? How to fix this?

full output for comparison.
http://pastebin.com/0zcf7Szk
http://pastebin.com/UgWgqpJz

As you can see, the only difference is the plugged usb port.

Comment: With an other attribute? Add the full output `for d in /dev/video*; do echo $d; udevadm info -a $d; done` here http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @A.B. added pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a script to find unoccupied device index by pattern. It accepts a printf pattern like `/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-fushicai_usbtv007_300000000002-video-index%d` and finds the first non-existent file.

Took existing rule from systemd package and rewrote it to use the script result instead of `ATTR{index}`. Since `ATTR{index}` is unmodifiable, decided to use my own directory for symlinks.

/etc/udev/rules.d/65-persistent-v4l-my.rules :

```
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="my_fix_v4l_index_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="video4linux", GOTO="my_fix_v4l_index_end"
ENV{MAJOR}=="", GOTO="my_fix_v4l_index_end"

IMPORT{program}="v4l_id $devnode"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"

KERNEL=="video*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", ENV{UNOCCUPIED_PATTERN}="v4l/by-id-my/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-video-index%%d"
IMPORT{program}="/usr/local/bin/find-unoccupied-device-index /dev/$env{UNOCCUPIED_PATTERN}"
KERNEL=="video*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="v4l/by-id-my/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-video-index$env{UNOCCUPIED_INDEX}"


LABEL="my_fix_v4l_index_end"
```

/usr/local/bin/find-unoccupied-device-index :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e    
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
  >&2 echo "usage: ${0##*/} prefix-%d-suffix"
  exit 1
fi

echo "pattern: $1" >&2

for ((i=0;;i++)); do
  filename=`printf "$1" $i`
  [ -e "$filename" ] || break
done
echo "unoccupied index: $i" >&2
echo "UNOCCUPIED_INDEX=$i"
```